# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object Tqdm

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have gone through several sources in stackoverflow regarding this issue, but couldn't resolve it.
Thus I have posted it here, kindly resolve.

```
# Combining all the above statemennts 
from tqdm import tqdm
Other_skill = []
# tqdm is for printing the status bar
for sentance in tqdm(project_data['Other skills'].values):
    sent = decontracted(sentance)
    sent = sent.replace('\\r', ' ')
    sent = sent.replace('\\"', ' ')
    sent = sent.replace('\\n', ' ')
    sent = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', ' ', sent)
    sent = ' '.join(e for e in sent.split() if e not in stopwords)
    Other_skill.append(sent.lower().strip())
```

Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-30687b6f17e1> in <module>()
      4 # tqdm is for printing the status bar
      5 for sentance in tqdm(project_data['Other skills'].values):
----> 6     sent = decontracted(sentance)
      7     sent = sent.replace('\\r', ' ')
      8     sent = sent.replace('\\"', ' ')

<ipython-input-7-a344e4b38b78> in decontracted(phrase)
      4 def decontracted(phrase):
      5     # specific
----> 6     phrase = re.sub(r"won't", "will not", phrase)
      7     phrase = re.sub(r"can\'t", "can not", phrase)
      8 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\re.py in sub(pattern, repl, string, count, flags)
    189     a callable, it's passed the match object and must return
    190     a replacement string to be used."""
--> 191     return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
    192 
    193 def subn(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: What is the type of `sentance` ? it should be a string or bytes-like object.

Comment: sentance is in string format

Comment: print(sent)      Arduino C Programming C Programming Firebase HTML MongoDB Node js Python ReactJS Redux jQuery CSS Django JavaScript

Comment: Anyone kindly help out!

Comment: It's difficult. We need to know what `project_data['Other skills']` is. It must have something that is not a string but we cannot guess what.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the brackets in the values() is needed. If i am correct project_data is an dictionary and you missed the brackets in values

```
from tqdm import tqdm
Other_skill = []
# tqdm is for printing the status bar 
# the values must have round brackets
for sentance in tqdm(project_data['Other skills'].values()):
    sent = decontracted(sentance)
    sent = sent.replace('\\r', ' ')
    sent = sent.replace('\\"', ' ')
    sent = sent.replace('\\n', ' ')
    sent = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', ' ', sent)
    sent = ' '.join(e for e in sent.split() if e not in stopwords)
    Other_skill.append(sent.lower().strip())
```

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-d6eee10821c9> in <module>()
      3 Other_skill = []
      4 # tqdm is for printing the status bar
----> 5 for sentance in tqdm(project_data['Other skills'].values()):
      6     sent = decontracted(sentance)
      7     sent = sent.replace('\\r', ' ')

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Comment: I followed same but getting error TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Comment: provide tha project data dictionary

Comment: project data is not in dictionary but string format

Comment: print(sent) Arduino C Programming C Programming Firebase HTML MongoDB Node js Python ReactJS Redux jQuery CSS Django JavaScript

Comment: what does decontracted function do, provide stopwards

Comment: Please provide everything i mentioned in the question and in the correct format

Comment: stopwords= ['i', 'me', 'my', 'myself', 'we', 'our', 'ours', 'ourselves', 'you', "you're", "you've",\
            "you'll", "you'd", 'your', 'yours', 'yourself', 'yourselves', 'he', 'him', 'his', 'himself', \
            'she', "she's.......]

Comment: import re

def decontracted(phrase):
    # specific
    phrase = re.sub(r"won't", "will not", phrase)
    phrase = re.sub(r"can\'t", "can not", phrase)

    # general
    phrase = re.sub(r"n\'t", " not", phrase)
    phrase = re.sub(r"\'re", " are", phrase)
    phrase = re.sub(r"\'s", " is", phrase)
    phrase = re.sub(r"\'d", " would", phrase)
    phrase = re.sub(r"\'ll", " will", phrase)
    phrase = re.sub(r"\'t", " not", phrase)
    phrase = re.sub(r"\'ve", " have", phrase)
    phrase = re.sub(r"\'m", " am", phrase)
    return phrase

Comment: decontracted function removes unwanted phrases

Comment: sent = decontracted(project_data['Other skills'].values[2000])
print(sent) ---------

Comment: Arduino, C Programming, C++ Programming, Firebase, HTML, MongoDB, Node.js, Python, ReactJS, Redux, jQuery, CSS, Django, JavaScript

Comment: sent = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', ' ', sent)
print(sent)  removes commas etc

Comment: Arduino C Programming C Programming Firebase HTML MongoDB Node js Python ReactJS Redux jQuery CSS Django JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the stacktrace we can see that `sub` is given a wrong input in `decontracted`.

Best would be to place a breakpoint where the arrow is to check the value of phrase:

```
      4 def decontracted(phrase):
      5     # specific
----> 6     phrase = re.sub(r"won't", "will not", phrase)
```

---

If you do not know how to do so, you can add some debugging code like so:

```
  def decontracted(phrase):
      # specific
      print(f'phrase: {phrase}\ttype: {type(phrase)}')
      phrase = re.sub(r"won't", "will not", phrase)
      [...]
```

This will print each *phrase* given to *decontracted* and its type. There should only be `bytes` or `str`. If not then you find your bug and can correct it accordingly.

---

I hope it helps, we do not have enough information to help you more.